# Vue: Binding background-image style not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my data I have a variable called image that holds the url of my image like so: (This is the correct url as it works when I bind an image src to img tags)

```
data () {
   return {
     image: "../../assets/img/hk.jpg"
   } 
}
```

I then have this:

```
<div class="container" v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')' }">
```

And basically the image is not showing up. No errors in the console either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
image: require("../../assets/img/hj.jpg")
```